# BundleUrl return nil

Tags: swift, bundle

I have an application which project hierarchy like this;

```
ProjectApp
-AppNative
ProjectAppTest
ProjecUIAppTests
```

I have an public class swift and  ı want to get bundleURL :

```
public class AppBundle {
   
   static var bundle : Bundle = AppBundle.initBundle()
    
   class func initBundle() -> Bundle {
       let podBundle = Bundle(for: AppBundle.self)
       let bundleURL = podBundle.url(forResource: "ProjectApp", withExtension: "bundle")
       return Bundle(url: bundleURL!)!
    }
}
```

bundleURL return nil. I can not get it. How can I fix it?

Comment: So you have a file ProjectApp.bundle in your project?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson yes.

Comment: @Thanks  I use it but ı found solution podBundle.bundleURL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use .bundleURL to access bundleURL;

```
public class AppBundle {
   
   static var bundle : Bundle = AppBundle.initBundle()
    
   class func initBundle() -> Bundle {
       let podBundle = Bundle(for: AppBundle.self)
       let bundleURL = podBundle.bundleURL
       return Bundle(url: bundleURL!)!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Click on **+** Button in **copy Bundle resources** and add you file.
Then you will get the path correctly.

[image: Check here]